# cross product evaluations

Tags: cross-product

Within vector calculus I am trying to evaluate the following vector equation.
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol A \times (\boldsymbol B \times \boldsymbol C),\qquad \boldsymbol C = \boldsymbol B\times \boldsymbol A
\end{equation}
My attempts are to evaluate the triple vector product as a dot product but no luck. I believe the result should yield, 
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol B \times \big( (\boldsymbol A \cdot \boldsymbol A) \cdot \boldsymbol B\big)
\end{equation}

Answer (score 0):

$$A \times (B\times C)=A\times(B\times(B\times A))$$
$$=A\times(B(A\cdot B)-A(B\cdot B))$$
$$=(A\cdot B)(A\times B)-(B\cdot B)(A\times A)$$
$$=(A\cdot B)(A\times B)$$